# I am getting some garbage value while sending file data through socket to server? Why?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am setting up a client server connection through sockets in C++. I am successfully connecting them but while sending filesize  and file data i am receiving some garbage values also in my server.

I am firstly sending File Size through send system call from client and then sending file Buffer to server.

I have recv system call in server which is successfully receiving Filesize, but while getting File data after some bytes i am getting garbage.

Client Code

```
File = fopen("index.jpg", "rb");
if (!File)
{
    MessageBox(L"Error while readaing the file");

}
fseek(File, 0, SEEK_END);
Size = ftell(File);
fseek(File, 0, SEEK_SET);

char* Buffer = new char[Size];

fread(Buffer, Size, 1, File);



char cSize[MAX_PATH];
sprintf(cSize, "%lu", Size);



send(Socket, cSize, MAX_PATH, 0); // File size
send(Socket, Buffer, Size, 0); // File Binary
```

Server Code

```
          unsigned long Size;
    char *Filesize = new char[1024];

    if (recv(Sub, Filesize, 1024, 0)) // File size
    {
       Size = strtoul(Filesize, NULL, 0);  //getting filesize
    }


    Buffer = new char[Size];
    int reader = recv(Sub, Buffer, Size, 0);
    Buffer[Size] = '\0';
    if (reader == -1) // File Binary
    {
        MessageBox(L"Perror Recv");
    }
    else if (reader == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(L"Connection is Closed");
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *File;
        File = fopen("test.jpg", "wb");
        fwrite((const char*)Buffer, 1, Size, File);  
        MessageBox(L"DATA Received");
        fclose(File);
    }
```

Comment: so why would you want to tag [tag:c]?

Comment: Check the values returned by `send` and `recv`.  -1 is returned on error, but you may get positive numbers less then your desired size indicating for partial completion.  In this case, you'll want to iterate and continue where the prior request left off.

Comment: Your don't check the results of `send()`. It does not guarantee that it will send all the bytes. It returns the number of bytes sent.

Comment: https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/04/08/socket-programming-in-c-version-1/index.html

Comment: You check the result of `recv()` is not zero. **BUT** the result is not a true/false value. It returns the number of bytes received. Which may not be the number sent (they may come later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you aren't handling the return values from `recv()` correctly.  For example:

```
if (recv(Sub, Filesize, 1024, 0)) // File size
```

... when the function quoted above returns, it has written some number of bytes (more than 0, less than 1025) into `Filesize`.  How many?  Your program doesn't know, because you didn't store the return value into a variable to find out (rather you only checked it to see if it was non-zero, or not, then discarded the value).  Therefore, it's entirely likely that `Filesize` contains not only your file size value, but the some portion of your file's data as well... which is why that portion of your file's data won't get written to disk later on in your program.

A similar problem is here:

```
int reader = recv(Sub, Buffer, Size, 0);
```

You check `reader` to see if it is `-1` or `0` (which is good), but in your final case you just `fwrite()` out `Size` bytes from the array, when `Buffer` contains `reader` bytes, not `Size` bytes (and `reader` could have any value between `1` and `Size`, depending on how many bytes the TCP stack decided to deliver to you in that particular `recv()` call.

One more problem is that you send `MAX_PATH` bytes for the file size, but you receive (up to) 1024 bytes for file size.  Is `MAX_PATH` equal to 1024?  If not, then even if `recv()` did fill out all 1024 bytes, your sender and receiver would still be out of sync with each other, since the excess bytes would show up in future `recv()` calls, or (alternatively) you'd get bytes from subsequent `send()` calls placed into your FileSize buffer.

So that's the direct problem -- I think the underlying problem is that you are making some assumptions about how TCP network works that are not true.  In particular:

- There is no guarantee of a one-to-one correspondence between `send()` and `recv()` calls.  (TCP is a byte-stream protocol and doesn't do any data-framing)
- You cannot rely on N bytes of data from a single call to `send()` being delivered via a single call to `recv()`.  The bytes you `send()` will be delivered in order, but there are no guarantees about how many calls to `recv()` it will require to receive them all, nor about how many bytes any given call to `recv()` will write into your receive-buffer.
- You cannot rely on `recv()` to fill up the entire buffer you passed to it.  `recv()` will write as few or as many bytes as it wants to, and it's up to your code to handle it correctly regardless of how many bytes it gets per `recv()` call.

In practice, this means you'll need to call `recv()` in a loop, and keep careful track of the return value from each `recv()` call, so you always know exactly how many bytes you've received so far and therefore where inside your buffer the next `recv()` call should start writing at.

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling the responses of send and recv function make sure you collect that as there are number of bytes send and receive and further use them were ever required.